# XAMPP-VM for max osx, with PHP 7.4.5 cannot find the var_input_vars

Tags: php, xampp-vm

I have been trying to increase the limit of the max_input_vars from the etc/php.ini. The problem is that I cannot find this variable to increase the limit. The image below shows the message that I get from the phpmyadmin of XAMPP-VM in the localhost. I need some help to fix this problem. Thank you!

[image: message from the phpmyadmin in xamppvm]

Comment: Create an entry for this in the php.ini config. Also please make sure you read the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars  This can be vulnerable to DDOS Attack